# JSON.parse() is using the same id value for every item in array (javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, shopify

I am working in Shopify and I am trying to output a json string into the page and then parse it with javascript to do a couple different things but it seems to be changing my data.

The string im trying to parse is:

```
{"options":["Size","Material"],"variants":[{"id": "46081919484183"},{"id": "46081919516951"},{"id": "46081919549719"},{"id": "46081919582487"},{"id": "46081919615255"},{"id": "46081919648023"}]}
```

Im using jQuery for this project so I am using `$form.find('.pdp-atc__data').text()` to get the string of text and it returns:

```
{"options":["Size","Material"],"variants":[{"id": "46081919484183"},{"id": "46081919516951"},{"id": "46081919549719"},{"id": "46081919582487"},{"id": "46081919615255"},{"id": "46081919648023"}]}
```

So far so good, but then when I use json parse this way `var data = JSON.parse($form.find('.pdp-atc__data').text());`

It outputs this:

```
{
    "options": [
        "Size",
        "Material"
    ],
    "variants": [
        {
            "id": "46081919484183"
        },
        {
            "id": "46081919484183"
        },
        {
            "id": "46081919484183"
        },
        {
            "id": "46081919484183"
        },
        {
            "id": "46081919484183"
        },
        {
            "id": "46081919484183"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I just tried to parse the "string" your query returns and JSON.parse did it's part correctly, so I'd suggest you looking into your html where you get your data from